# String concatenation in SE 4.1 SELECT statement

Tags: informix

I'm using ISQL-SE 4.1 and need to concatenate two CHAR strings in a SELECT statement. I tried using the two pipe symbols || but that doesnt work in 4.1 is there another way to do the trick, maybe using subscripts [a,b] or using a temporary file without having to resort to ESQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenate operators were introduced in Version 5.00.  The functions were introduced even later.

There isn't a way to directly concatenate strings in the SQL dialect of Informix SE 4.10.

If you need string concatenation in SQL, upgrade to a more recent version of SE.  (I note that Version 4.10 was originally released in about 1989.)

Alternatively, if you are writing a report, then you can select the individual strings and concatenate in the ACE report.

Comment: I cannot upgrade to version 5.00 of isql because 4.10 is the highest version available under MS-DOS, so is there an indirect way (trick) for concatenating 2 strings without resorting to cperf or ESQL/C?

Comment: I don't know of one, no.  Sorry.  And I know of the constraints you operate under.

Comment: perhaps col_1 CHAR(10)... UPDATE table SET col_1[1,5] = col_2, col_1[6,10] = col_3;

Comment: Try it and see; I'm not sure I'd hold my breath, though I may be doing the old system an injustice by being somewhat dubious.  If your strings are fixed length, as that requires, then there's at least a chance.  If the strings are not fixed length, then you're on thinner ice.

Comment: tes, they're fixed length (no VARCHAR's in SE).. in my case, I want to append a sequential suffix to an item id. example: A12345-1, B12345-2 ..